# Ошибка при сохранении тестовой версии приложения на play console (664550CB)

Tags: unity3d, google-play-console

Когда пытаюсь сохранить данные на странице создание открытой тестовой версии в
Google Play Console, появляется ошибка: "Произошла непредвиденная ошибка. Попробуйте ещё раз. (664550CB)". Подскажите, что эта за ошибка и как исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Для разрешения этой ошибки необходимо ввести описание в поле "примечание к выпуску".